# Django 1.9 angularjs 1.5 template tags

Tags: angularjs, django

I know there are quite a few solution out there it seems as I've already done some searching. However, it seems the vast majority of them are for older versions Django and AngularJS.

That said, if I'm using Django 1.9 and AngularJS 1.5 - what would be the "best practice" way to implement Django and AngularJS with the well known issue of conflicting template tags.

1. I'm using AngularJS to implement a site search feature and need a way to display the results. It seems that {% verbatim %} and {% endverbatim %} would be the simplest, cleanest way to achieve this?
2. I've also thought of packaging the AngularJS up into a directive and simply adding the directive to the Django results page? Would that work as intended?
3. As the comment below suggests, decoupling and using $ajax calls. Which I assume would involve Django Rest Framework (never used before)?

Comment: It would be cleaner for you to decouple the two and use ajax calls to exchange data between front end and backend

Comment: @Incognos so have Django and AngularJS work independently of each other?

Comment: they are both frameworks, use django as your API endpoint (using something like django rest framework or tastypie) and have angular make API requests using ajax ($http)

Comment: https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial#serializing-the-account-model

Comment: @Incognos thank you!